# How to do authentication with redis in node.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, redis, node-redis

I'm using the  node_redis module and I'm not being able to determine a password for redis succesfully.

Here's my code:

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient(6379, "localhost"); 

client.auth("password", function (err) { if (err) throw err; });
```

Whenever I run this file in the command line I get the following message: "Redis does not require a password, but a password was supplied."

I keep getting the same error, even though I tried to change the **redis.conf** file that is in my computer's redis instalation:

```
requirepass password
```

Please, shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the redis server use this command:
    redis-server /path/to/redis.conf

this way it will authenticate connections using password specified in redis.conf